# Netflix on Ubuntu Black screen

Tags: 12.10, 64-bit, netflix

I've installed Netflix-desktop using the `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ehoover/compholio`  method. See [this link](http://www.iheartubuntu.com/2012/11/ppa-for-netflix-desktop-app.html) for the whole thing.  It works great up until I select a show. After I select a show I get a black screen. I have a dual monitor setup, but I removed one hoping that was the problem. I'm running Ubuntu 12.10 on an amd 64-bit. I've uninstalled reinstalled. Reinstalled from command line, from software center, et. al.  I'm using standard Ubuntu drivers for my video.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out reinstalling covers over a multitude of errors.  I think I failed to install one of the windows dependencies.